# Microsoft OAuth redirects with 302 instead of 200, which breaks deep link logic on mobile device

Tags: redirect, azure-active-directory, deep-linking, http-status-code-302

What I am using OAuth to authenticate with Microsoft:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize...&redirect_uri=MYURL`
(I also use similar approach with google: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth...redirect_uri=MYURL`)

MYURL is https://admin.myrealdomain.com/code
(MYURL is an empty 200 Ok page on my server)

However, Microsoft Graph returns with **302 redirect** from `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf...`

and this causes issues with deeplinks handling (the page just is not intercepted by the app).

I **don't have** any such **issues with Google** though (200 status code).
And it seems like it recently worked just fine with Microsoft as well. I am just not sure if this is something I miss or MS has some recent changes applied to that logic.

Does anyone has any idea how I can solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Using Microsoft authorization will indeed redirect to 'https: //login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf ...', but I don't understand it 'and this causes issues with deeplinks handling (the page just is not intercepted by the app ) 'Can you say more details?

Comment: Which authentication flow are you using?

Comment: Regularly, when the response returns from authentication provider (and as it works with Google), it returns without extra step (I don't see exact flow of redirects when trying it on Desktop Chrome, but it shows just return to my return_url, but in case of MS it's 302 to oauth20_authorize.srf first). So, when it returns from Google, the deeplinking mechanics recognizes the url and returns the control to the mobile app. But in case with MS, nothing happens, even though the final return_url page is the same as with Google in the end.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are executing the OAUTH code flow behind the scenes. It doesn't work this way.

You should pop up a browser dialog to request the authorization code. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#protocol-diagram).

The steps:

1. Pop up a browser dialog which the url address is
   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...`
2. After User signs in, it redirects to the redirect url, where the
   authorization code has been returned.
3. POST to
   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?....`
   you can get the access token to call Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "it doesn't work this way", when it already does. :)
This is how it's already organized, and everything works fine, except only with Microsoft. Google is ok.